# Merge tuples on specified filed

Tags: python, tuples

I have array of tuples in format `(date, user_id, amount)` like this:

```
[
  ('2020-10-01', 1, 1000), 
  ('2020-10-01', 2, 2000), 
  ('2020-10-01', 3, 3000), 
  ('2020-10-01', 1, 4000),
  ('2020-10-01', 3, 5000)
]
```

what I want to do is combine amount for same user_id like this:

```
[
  ('2020-10-01', 1, 5000), 
  ('2020-10-01', 2, 2000), 
  ('2020-10-01', 3, 8000)
]
```

How can I do that in python? Thank you!

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
import pandas as pd 

data = [
  ('2020-10-01', 1, 1000), 
  ('2020-10-01', 2, 2000), 
  ('2020-10-01', 3, 3000), 
  ('2020-10-01', 1, 4000),
  ('2020-10-01', 3, 5000)
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date','id','value'])
result = df.groupby(['date','id']).sum().reset_index()
result2 = result.to_dict(orient='records')
[(r['date'], r['id'], r['value']) for r in result2]
```